# Strange names for revisions?

Tags: svn

I'm working at a company that has a strange policy. They can't stick to a single name for a software revision. For some reason they have branches, versions, releases and perhaps another term. They never explain what these mean.

What is the standard way to separate out different revisions to be less confusing?

Comment: the title could match the question more closely (technically, it is no question). Maybe sth like 'Whats the difference between revision,version,branch,release'?

Answer (score 6):

Why not ask them? And those are all commonly used terms for different things - a release is a revision that makes it to the outside world, a branch is a revision that is being worked on in parallel and a version is (possibly) a revision that someone has tagged with a version number.

Comment: I have... The ones in positions of authority can't answer the question articulately. The underlings refuse to help coworkers and/or can't answer the question.

Comment: Wow I'd be working on my resume in a situation like that.  Sounds pretty toxic.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, that a revision may also be a branch, a version and a release.

Those terms are sometimes used a little fuzzy, and my use may not be the definitive one. That said, in my nomenclature,

- a **revision** is a well definied snapshot of the project
- a **branch** is a named set of revisions, developed beside other branches. It is not uncommon to call the lastest revision of that set 'the branch' as well.
- a **version** is a revision that has been given a numerical name (i.e., the version number)
- a **release** is a version, that was given to the customers, or made public otherwise)  (it may also refer to the process of releasing).

Comment: You mean a revision is merely my checked out copy?

Comment: @funderbolt: as i use the term: yes. i kinda use 'a commit' and 'a revision' synonymously. ymmv.

Comment: @funderbolt actually a revision would be the copy you check back in.

Comment: I've also used the word "copy" as in "my copy".